# Can't receive email to additional account added in Apple Mail - Error 550 5.1.10 in Exchange Online

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

I'm trying to add an additional SMTP account to someone's apple Mail program.

They can send emails fine, but when I try to send them an email I get:
"Your message to x@y.com couldn't be delivered.
x wasn't found at y.com.

The settings all look good in the Mail program. They also have Microsoft Exchange email set up the and it's as if it's interfering with the receiving of the SMTP email. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Found [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online/fix-error-code-550-5-1-10-in-exchange-online) about your error code 550 5.1.10 issue, but it is more related to Microsoft Outlook client. Just check if it could helps. If this issue still continues, maybe you could found more information in the the dedicated forum for Apple Mail.